# How to save .csv file to a directory with a new file name

Tags: python, pandas, directory, jupyter-notebook, save

I am in Jupiter Lab working with a notebook. I need to use pandas/python code to save a .csv file to my computer under a specific directory, with a new name.

Problem is as follows: 
Save the data in your 'working' directory and name it "Data Problem 1"

I've tried numerous codes but this is one that seems like it should work.

```
import os.path

save_path = '/Users/ccheddar/Class700/Homework/Data/Working'

name_of_file = raw_input("Cityline_Calls_for_Service.csv")

completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file) 

file1 = open(completeName, "w")

toFile = raw_input("syr_service.csv")

file1.write(toFile)

file1.close()
```

I keep getting the error message:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-f34c54969f7c> in <module>
      3 save_path = '/Users/ccheddar/Class700/Homework/Data/Working'
      4 
----> 5 name_of_file = raw_input("Cityline_Calls_for_Service.csv")
      6 
      7 completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file)

NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined
```

Comment: What have you tried? Try giving an example of code you have tried and why it isn't working.

Comment: You are using Python 3 (which you *should* be using) but your code is written for Python 2. `raw_input` doesn't exist in Python 3, it is just simply `input`

Comment: Although actually, not sure why you would use `input`/`raw_input`, that's for taking user input. It looks like you just want those strings...

Comment: Thank you for your help! This code ended up doing what I needed to do: 
export_csv = df.to_csv (r'C:\Users\Ron\Desktop\export_dataframe.csv', index = None, header=True) #Don't forget to add '.csv' at the end of the path

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `raw_input`

```
import os.path

save_path = '/Users/ccheddar/Class700/Homework/Data/Working'

name_of_file = "Cityline_Calls_for_Service.csv"

completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file) 

file1 = open(completeName, "w")

toFile = "syr_service.csv"

file1.write(toFile)

file1.close()
```